# Intellij Http Client - use function() import from external js to initialize an inplace variable

Tags: variables, scope, intellij-14, http.client

I am currently transcribing a postman collection to intellij http client and even though most of the stuff did work I am currently stuck at a specific problem where I need an inplace Variable `@inplaceVar` (that is valid for all requests in the same http file) to be initialized with an external js function import

This is how it works for PreRequest variables:

```
< {%
  import {certainFunction} from 'script/source';
  request.variables.set("onetimeusevar", certainFunction());  
%}
```

PreRequest Variables are only valid for the following request though so I need to import a function from my external file.js to be used with an inplace variable `@inplaceVar` because as I said I want to reuse this var for other requests in the same file

I have certain ideas on how to solve the scoping issue

1. I could use `client.global.set("varname", function())` but that causes all sorts of inconsistencies that global variables bring in a multirequest test setup and is prone to bite me in the ...
2. Maybe I could create temporary `temp.js` file that I can initialize with the needed variables and overwrite for subsequent testruns/other http.files... Don't know how easy that is to implement though

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution for my case:

```
@sth = "ARTS{{$random.integer(111111111, 999999999)}}PPE";
```

The specifics for my string are not as complicated so I can do this inline on the variable itself without needing a function.